# Use one date format in whole project of cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, cakephp-3.1, cakephp-3.x

This might be a simple question.

Is there any way that I can set in my project just a single date format and have this date format everywhere. And by everywhere I mean the view, edit, index actions. The format I need to have is `Y-m-d H:i:s` and it has nothing to do with my locale date format.

I tried to use the following code inside bootstrap file but it didn't work

```
Type::build('date')->useLocaleParser()->setLocaleFormat('Y-m-d');
Type::build('datetime')->useLocaleParser()->setLocaleFormat('Y-m-d H:i');
```

In the index it kept showing the date as `10/10/15, 8:20 PM`.

Also for editing a date I use a text input so I need them to textbox to display the date as `2015/10/10 20:20`.

Comment: I'm not sure what `Type::build` is, but have you seen [Time](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.I18n.Time.html#_resetToStringFormat)?

Comment: What about it? I think you are suggesting to use this where ever I display a DateTime? But I want it globally. Set it once and leave things working. Or am I missing something in what you are suggesting?

Comment: You can definitely do that with `Time`, I believe that's how it was meant to be - and that's how I'm doing it in a similar situation with `Number` helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP has a number of utility classes and associate [helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html) that will do most of the repetitive or tough work for you.

In this case the [`Time`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html) utility class can take care of formating globally, if you [set it up](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.I18n.Time.html#_resetToStringFormat) with the default format you need.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you create a file/class which serves to house application CONST values, and then require that file/autoload that class in your application bootstrap file.

`define("MYSQL_DATETIME_FORMAT", "Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Then, define a property in your ApplicationController, such as `$mysql_datetime = MYSQL_DATETIME_FORMAT;`, and pass this value into your views, a view helper, or a decorator class.

You can also create a user defined or class defined callback (i.e., a helper) which uses this value and performs conversions for you (such as `function to_mysql_datetime($timeval){...}`. Then in your views, you could call:

`$formatted_datetime = DateFormatHelper::to_mysql_datetime($other_datetime_value);`

This is from the CakePHP documentation regarding this issue:

> If you have any additional configuration needs, you should add them to
>   your application’s config/bootstrap.php file. This file is included
>   before each request, and CLI command.
>
> This file is ideal for a number of common bootstrapping tasks:
>
> Defining convenience functions. 
>   Declaring constants.
>   Creating cache configurations.
>   Configuring inflections.
>   Loading configuration files.
>
> Be careful to maintain the MVC software design pattern when you add
>   things to the bootstrap file: it might be tempting to place formatting
>   functions there in order to use them in your controllers. As you’ll
>   see in the Controllers and Views sections there are better ways you
>   add custom logic to your application.

[Source](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#bootstrapping-cakephp)

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? I took it straight from the documentation. This is also a very common pattern for all MVC web applications.